# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'. in buttonclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting InvalidCastException .  from this code

```
protected void btnSaveOpeningBalance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AddItemBLL objAddItemsBll = new AddItemBLL();           
        List<SetItemDAO> objItmDAO = new List<SetItemDAO>();
        SetItemDAO objItmDAOMaster = new SetItemDAO();
        if (gvItem.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<gvItem.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);

                TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)gvItem.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].FindControl("txtQuantity");
                double qty = (txtQuantity.Text.Trim().Length > 0) ? Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text.Trim()) : 0;
                TextBox txtVal = (TextBox)gvItem.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].FindControl("txtValue");
                double val = (txtVal.Text.Trim().Length > 0) ? Convert.ToDouble(txtVal.Text.Trim()) : 0;

                objItmDAOMaster.ItemID = Convert.ToInt16(gvItem.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values["ItemID"]);
                objItmDAOMaster.ItmQty = qty;
                objItmDAOMaster.ItmVl = val;

                //objItmDAO.Add(objItmDAOMaster);
                bool result = objAddItemsBll.InsertItemBalance(objItmDAOMaster);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and give this error message 
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'."
i also try this

```
GridViewRow gvr = gvItem.Rows[gvItem.SelectedDataKey.Value];
```

but still get the same error .

Comment: because "NamingContainer" is a container and not gridviewrow.

Comment: Why not simply replace your loop for(int i = 0;.....) by foreach (GridViewRow row in gvItem.Rows) ?

Comment: Is `btnSaveOpeningBalance` inside the GridView? Because I think it is outside of it...

Comment: looping is not a problem 
i am facing problem with nameiing container